# How to select the List with most items?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Is there a way to compare two Lists and then return the List that contains the most items? Preferably with a snitzy and elegant LINQ query.

```
List<Item> listWithMostItems = List.Select(list1, list2, x => Math.Max(x.Count))
```

Comment: What is the code you put there?

Comment: @rmn36 I just made some up to show my idea of the code I was looking for

Comment: To Downvoters!!, Please don't down vote immediately. If you are not clear about question.. please ask again.

Comment: how do you want to handle ties?  Any single list, or all eligible lists?

Answer (score 5):

If you have just 2 lists [solution provided by Marrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32590576/1163867) will work best, but if you have more lists, let's say `IEnumerable<List<string>>` you'd be best either using [`MaxBy` from moreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) or sorting the input and taking first element from sorted collection:

```
List<Item> listWithMostItems = lists.OrderByDescending(x => x.Count).First();
```

Comment: This is the exact right answer since it does not assume the number of lists to be finite never mind 2.

Answer (score 3):

No need for Linq here:

```
 List<Item> listWithMostItems = list1.Count > list2.Count ? list1 : list2;
```

Just set the condition to get the list you want in case both lists contain the same number of elements

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way to go, depending on how you want to handle the case when the lists have an equal `Count`.

Comment: Cool. But if I'd have a hundred list, this probably would't be the best way to go

Comment: @silkfire You mean lists with hundreds of items, or hundreds of lists?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Lists, sorry ;-)

Comment: This works well for 2 or 3 lists but what if there are 100?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Item> listWithMostItems = list2.Count > list1.Count ? list2 : list1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the efficiency of this, but if you want something that selects the longest lists in a large collection of lists, you should compile a master `List< List<string> >` and order by their lengths.  If you more than one list with the same maximum length and you need all of them, then you need to `GroupBy` first.

```
var combinedLists = new List<List<string>> {list1, list2, list3, list4};
var groupsOfListsWithMaxLength = combinedLists
     .GroupBy( l => l.Count)
     .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
     .First(); //null handle if needed with FirstOrDefault


foreach (var strList in groupsOfListsWithMaxLength )
{
     //do stuff.  The first group is a collection of all lists with the max length
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zju65A)